# problems with Java GUI repainting JPanel JFrame

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, jtextarea, repaint

The plan is to have the program replace the lyrics on the screen with different lyrics when another song is searched.

```
}public void lyricPrinter(){
    if(scroll != null){
    scroll.removeAll(); //--> temporary test
    System.out.println("removed scroll");
    scroll.repaint();
    }

    JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(lyrics);
    textarea.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    textarea.setEditable(false);


    scroll = new JScrollPane (textarea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

    GUI.frame.remove(scroll);
    GUI.frame.add(scroll);
    GUI.frame.setVisible(true);




}
```

I thought using removeall() would do the trick but this ends up happening..

printing lyrics for the first time..
[image: printing lyrics for the first time..]
After I change the lyrics and try to replace the previous lyrics..
[image: After I change the lyrics and try to replace the previous lyrics..]

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a pansy, do you think you could demonstrate your program using a slightly less offensive/rubbish song?

Comment: `scroll.removeAll()` doesn't remove the scroll pane from the parent container, it simply removes the viewport associated with the scroll pane.  `GUI.frame.remove(scroll);` is pointless, because you've reassigned the variable with a new instance of `JScrollPane`, so the old scroll pane is never removed...but, why would you, simply change the `JViewport`'s view as HovercraftFullOfEels has suggested...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I don't even recommend that he change the viewport's view but rather that he simply change the JTextArea's text.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels sorry, you could add it though ;)

Answer (score 4):

- Why are you adding and removing components? This is kind of a backwards and dangerous way to achieve your goals.
- And even if your plan was OK, you don't actually remove the original JScrollPane anywhere. This call, `GUI.frame.remove(scroll);`, removes the ***new*** JScrollPane, the one not added yet, not an old one that currently resides in the GUI.
- Instead, why not concentrate on keeping components and swapping the data they hold -- their text? This is what I'd do and what I strongly recommend.
- Your `GUI.frame....` call suggests that you may be mis-using static fields. Your JFrame should not be held by a static field, unless you aren't concerned with maintaining encapsulation of data and behavior.

---

**Edit**
What I'm recommending is

- that you have a JTextArea field, one that holds the text of your song lyrics,
- that it be a non-static field in your class, visible throughout the class since it isn't declared inside of a constructor or method.
- that in your event code where you want to swap lyrics, you simply call `setText(...)` on this JTextArea variable, passing in a String containing the new lyrics.

---

So say you have a JTextArea called songLyricsTextArea, to swap text, all you'd do is

```
String newLyrics = somehowGetNewLyricsToSong(); 
songLyricsTextArea.setText(newLyrics);
```

For example, in the demo program below, I read in the java code for several demo programs held in the Java Swing tutorials. I place the program names in a JList on the right, and give the JList a ListSelectionListener that swaps the text in the JTextArea (here called programTextArea) similar to what I'm recommending that you do. The key code in my demo is in the listener here:

```
  demoList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

     @Override    // a new program has been selected
     public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
           if (demoList.getSelectedIndex() != -1) { // make sure selection valid
              DemoProgram demoProgram = demoList.getSelectedValue(); // get selection
              programTextArea.setText(demoProgram.getText());  // get text and pass into text area
           }
        }
     }
  });
```

The whole program, which you should compile and run to see how it works, is thus:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SwapTextExample extends JPanel {
   private static final String[][] DEMO_PROGS = {
         {     "BorderDemo.java",
               "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/"
                     + "components/BorderDemoProject/src/components/BorderDemo.java" },
         {     "ButtonDemo.java",
               "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/"
                     + "components/ButtonDemoProject/src/components/ButtonDemo.java" },
         {     "ButtonHtmlDemo.java",
               "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/"
                     + "components/ButtonHtmlDemoProject/src/components/ButtonHtmlDemo.java" },
         {     "CheckBoxDemo.java",
               "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/"
                     + "components/CheckBoxDemoProject/src/components/CheckBoxDemo.java" },
         {     "ComboBoxDemo.java",
               "http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/"
                     + "components/ComboBoxDemoProject/src/components/ComboBoxDemo.java" }, };

   private DefaultListModel<DemoProgram> model = new DefaultListModel<>();
   private JList<DemoProgram> demoList = new JList<DemoProgram>(model);
   private JTextArea programTextArea = new JTextArea(40, 70);

   public SwapTextExample() throws IOException {
      for (String[] demoProgText : DEMO_PROGS) {
         String name = demoProgText[0];
         String link = demoProgText[1];
         URL url = new URL(link);
         Scanner scanner = null;
         try {
            scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
               sb.append(scanner.nextLine() + "\n");
            }
            String text = sb.toString();
            DemoProgram demoProg = new DemoProgram(name, link, text);
            model.addElement(demoProg);
         } finally {
            if (scanner != null) {
               scanner.close();
            }
         }

      }

      demoList.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
      demoList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

         @Override    // a new program has been selected
         public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
            if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
               if (demoList.getSelectedIndex() != -1) { // make sure selection valid
                  DemoProgram demoProgram = demoList.getSelectedValue(); // get selection
                  programTextArea.setText(demoProgram.getText());  // get text and pass into text area
               }
            }
         }
      });

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(new JScrollPane(demoList), BorderLayout.WEST);
      add(new JScrollPane(programTextArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SwapTextExample mainPanel;
      try {
         mainPanel = new SwapTextExample();
         JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swap Text Example");
         frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
         frame.pack();
         frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
         frame.setVisible(true);
      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class DemoProgram {
   private String name;
   private String link;
   private String text;

   public DemoProgram(String name, String link, String text) {
      this.name = name;
      this.link = link;
      this.text = text;
   }

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public String getLink() {
      return link;
   }

   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return name;
   }
}
```

Comment: cheers for this insightful comment. I've already solved my problem but the way I fixed it made me realise how little I knew was actually going on in my code.

what do you mean about keeping components and swapping code? I tried just swapping the text assuming it would re-blit and automatically update it like i'm used to when game developing with pygame (python). But that wasn't the case, and instead, it kept the old text field and added a new one ontop of it.

So I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, because as far as I'm aware you have to manually remove the component to add the new one

Answer (score 0):

You never remove the old scroll pane. Move you GUI.frame.remove(scroll); up before the new scroll pane is created.

Comment: Cheers, I did exactly this. Rookie mistake I know, one of those things I completely missed then became obvious one I discovered my mistake.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by simply removing the text area and then readding the updated one. Alot easier than removing the text from the scrollpane but still keeping the actual pane and then trying to add a new one on top of it..

```
}public void lyricPrinter(){
    if(scroll != null){
    //scroll.removeAll(); //--> temporary test
    //System.out.println("removed scroll");
    //scroll.repaint();
    GUI.frame.remove(scroll);
    }

    JTextArea textarea = new JTextArea(lyrics);
    textarea.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    textarea.setEditable(false);


    scroll = new JScrollPane (textarea,JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS,JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);


    GUI.frame.add(scroll);
    GUI.frame.setVisible(true);




}
```

Comment: This makes no sense. Again, why the hell are you swapping JTextAreas and not simply swapping the ***text*** held by them? Just simply calling `setText(newText)` on the existing JTextArea is *all* that needs to be done. Your code does heavy lifting when all you need to do is turn the page. Crazy.

Comment: I'll try this again, but I feel there was a reason why I didn't do this because of issues automatically refreshing it.

Comment: A JTextArea refreshes automatically when setText is called. None of this code above is needed which is why your current plan is madness.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels

I just tried altering my code, so all it does is change the text 'textarea' contains and then repainting. this did absolutely nothing to the graphics.